# create a temp datatable to store values of records

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, dataset, batch-processing

Need help with dataset I am working on   I have a  dataset with 2 tables  one holds only the primary key values  which is "Statementnumber" and the other hold a rest of the details   with one to many relationship

now I want to parse through each statementnumber from my one table get the details from the second table and place that record into a new data table. one  record at a time using a for loop till I reach the end of records from my primary table.  how can I do this is c#?

So far I have both tables in the same dataset.

here is the code I have already.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            OracleConnection connection;
            OracleDataAdapter OracleAdapter;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string firstSql = null;


            connetionString = "DataSoruce

            connection = new OracleConnection(connetionString);
            firstSql = @"SELECT DISTINCT statement_header.statementnumber,
                     statement_details.invoicedate,
                     statement_details.invoicenumber,
                     statement_details.invoicetotal,
                     statement_details.doc_type,
                     statement_header.statementtotal,
                     statement_details.bunumber_ru,
                     statement_details.bunumber,
                     statement_details.description,
                     statement_details.reference_number,
                     statement_header.remto_zip,
                     statement_header.remto_city,
                     statement_header.remto_state,
                     statement_header.remto_mailname,
                     statement_header.remto_addr1,
                     statement_header.remto_addr2,
                     statement_header.remto_addr3,
                     statement_header.soldto_city,
                     statement_header.soldto_state,
                     statement_header.soldto_zip,
                     statement_header.soldto_addr1,
                     statement_header.soldto_addr2,
                     statement_header.soldto_addr3,
                     statement_header.balance_forward,
                     statement_header.statementdate,
                     statement_header.custid,
                     statement_header.custname,
                     statement_header.phone_prefix,
                     statement_header.phone_number,
                     statement_details.purchases,
                     statement_details.payments,
                     statement_details.misc_credit2,
                     statement_details.misc_credit1,
                     statement_header.company_number,
                     statement_header.statementpurchases,
                     statement_header.statementpayments,
                     statement_header.statementmisc_credit1,
                     statement_header.statementmisc_credit2,
                     statement_header.nomailnoprint,
                     statement_header.SOLDTOCOUNTRYCODE,
                     statement_header.SOLDTOCOUNTRYNAME,
                     statement_header.CREDITZEROFLAG
       FROM STATEMENT_DATA_DOMESTIC statement_header
            INNER JOIN STATEMENT_DATA_DOM_DETAILS statement_details
               ON statement_header.statementnumber =
                     statement_details.statementnumber";
            string secondSql = "select statementnumber from statement_data_domestic";
                connection.Open();
                OracleAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(firstSql, connection);
                OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "domestic");
                OracleAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(secondSql, connection);
                OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "statement");

            OracleAdapter.Dispose();
                connection.Close();

                ds.Relations.Add("Statementnumber", ds.Tables["statement"].Columns["statementnumber"], ds.Tables["domestic"].Columns["statementnumber"]);



    //GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
           //   GridView1.DataBind();
                ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
                reportDoc.Load(@"c:\users\soniara\desktop\statement.rpt");
                DataTable d3 = ds.Tables["statement"];
                foreach (DataRow arpan in d3.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow[] details = arpan.GetChildRows("Statementnumber");


                    foreach (DataRow detail in details)
                    {

                        reportDoc.SetDataSource(detail);
                        ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
                        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = @"d:\Converte5_1_13"+detail+".pdf";
                        CrExportOptions = reportDoc.ExportOptions;
                        {
                            CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                            CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                            CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                            CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;

                        }
                        reportDoc.Export();

                    }
                }








        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want to retrieve one record at time from my statement table and get all the details from details table and  run it through crystal report  to get a pdf output

My code works just fine if I do  just give the entire dataset as source to crytalreport.setdatasrouce

but  it makes a one long  pdf file and not small single statement files. which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: This sounds like you want to make a complete copy of your second table, or am I missing something? Do you have records in your second tabel which don't correspond to a record of your first table and you want to filter the second table with values from the first one or what are you trying to do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us what you have already attempted.

Comment: well What I am trying to do is have a key value pair  and run  each  record  to crystal report  line by line and export it to PDF.

Comment: here is the code  I have so far ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Replaced]
If CrystalReports supports a DataView object as datasource, you can use this:

```
        foreach (DataRow statementRow in ds.Tables["statement"].Rows)
        {
            var detail = new DataView(ds.Tables["domestic"])
            {
                RowFilter = String.Format("statementnumber = {0}", statementRow["statementnumber"]),
                Sort = "" // optional
            };


            reportDoc.SetDataSource(detail);
                            ....
                      }
```

Otherwise you can use this:

```
    foreach (DataRow statementRow in ds.Tables["statement"].Rows)
    {
        var detail = GetFilteredTable(ds.Tables["domestic"], statementRow["statementNumber"]);

        reportDoc.SetDataSource(detail);
                        ....
    }


    public DataTable GetFilteredTable(DataTable dt, object statementNumber)
    {
        var detailRows = dt.Select(String.Format("statementnumber = {0}", statementNumber));
        var filteredDt = dt.Clone();
        foreach (var detailRow in detailRows)
        {
            filteredDt.Rows.Add(detailRow.ItemArray);
        }
        return filteredDt;
    }
```

Another suggestion is that you might want to investigate grouping in Crystal reports, you might be able to achieve what you need by creating a parameter for the statement number and passing it into the report itself, and have it filter for you.  I do not know the details but I know that it is possible.

Comment: is there a way to get single record out at a time and place it in a another data table, based on the relation defined above ?

Comment: You should be able to copy a row at a time.  To create an empty copy of your DataTable, use DataTable.Clone.  Then you can add a row to it by copying the DataRow's ItemArray into it.

Comment: I get your point but my statement numbers are in separate table.  is there a where clause or something I can use  to get specific row example would be copy all rows from domestic into new dataset where statement number from statement = statement number from domestic.

Comment: Ok, I understand your question now better, sorry I didn't look at your code in detail first.  I replaced my answer, I hope this helps.

Comment: the second approach does cut down on time by 8 minutes  but I think I am also going to look into brusting the report  itself see if that does anything different.   ill post my findings.